# PIL Unidentified Image Error when running my CNN model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

new programmer here so forgive the possible lack of detail/knowledge.
Whenever I run my model.fit(), the first epoch runs halfway then gives me the following error:
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fad89356680>
How can I either skip the image that's generating the error or fix the issue entirely?

Relevant code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30,
                            width_shift_range=20,
                            height_shift_range=20,
                            horizontal_flip=True,
                            rescale=1/255,
                            zoom_range=0.3,
                            fill_mode='nearest')
image_gen.flow_from_directory(trainpath)
Found 16418 images belonging to 120 classes.
<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator at 0x7fad88ea1f40>
test_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
test_gen.flow_from_directory(testpath)
Found 2153 images belonging to 120 classes.
<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator at 0x7fad88ea4ee0>
Model

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPool2D, Flatten
model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=img_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=img_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=img_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(120, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 98, 98, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 49, 49, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 47, 47, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 23, 23, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 21, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 10, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 6400)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 128)               819328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 120)               15480     
=================================================================
Total params: 891,128
Trainable params: 891,128
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
earlystop=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
batch_size=16
train_image_gen=image_gen.flow_from_directory(trainpath,
                                             target_size=img_shape[:2],
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             class_mode='categorical')
Found 16418 images belonging to 120 classes.
test_image_gen=image_gen.flow_from_directory(testpath,
                                             target_size=img_shape[:2],
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                            shuffle=False)
Found 2153 images belonging to 120 classes.
from PIL import Image
results=model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,
                            epochs=20,
                           validation_data=test_image_gen,
                           callbacks=[earlystop])
/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1940: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
Epoch 1/20
 109/1027 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2:18 - loss: 4.7821 - accuracy: 0.0110
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-155640c4966a> in <module>
----> 1 results=model.fit_generator(train_image_gen,
      2                             epochs=20,
      3                            validation_data=test_image_gen,
      4                            callbacks=[earlystop])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1941                   'will be removed in a future version. '
   1942                   'Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.')
-> 1943     return self.fit(
   1944         generator,
   1945         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    915       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3021       (graph_function,
   3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3025 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1958         and executing_eagerly):
   1959       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1960       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1961           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1962     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    589       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    590         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 591           outputs = execute.execute(
    592               str(self.signature.name),
    593               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fad89356680>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 249, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 645, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 961, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 837, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 963, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 227, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img = load_img(filepaths[j],

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fad89356680>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3481]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Similar kind of situation occur with me few days ago. I handle it by removing the images that cause this type of error. To do this I use exception handling. Try adding exception handling to refine your images dataset, it is possible that this also work for you as it worked in my case.
[image]

As you can see I iterate through my whole image dataset and check which image causing error, so I print its address and remove it, in my case I have dataset of persons and I'm extracting features, on some images it gives error and crash my program, so I refine my dataset like that and successfully get my results.
In your case you can add try-catch, while opening images, if image open successfully then ok, but if not then remove it.
Code of that look like this.

```
from PIL import Image
try:
     Image.open(image_address)
except:
     print('Error occur on ' + image_address)
```

Comment: Could you possibly add some example code?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can happen fairly often in particular when you use datasets from other people say on Kagle that has not had much use and have bad image files within the data set. You used flow_from_directory. Notice in the parameter list it does NOT have a parameter called validate_filenames . If you look at flow_from_dataframe it does have this parameter. The documentation states

```
validate_filenames: Boolean, whether to validate image filenames in x_col.
If True, invalid images will be ignored. 
Disabling this option can lead to speed-up in the execution of this function. Defaults to True.
```

I do not know if flow_from_directory does this check on the image files but I expect it does not. So I think the first thing to do is to use flow_from_dataframe and see if it will detect the bad image file or files and skip over them. Below is the code you can use to read in you images. I will assume you have a directory structure similar to that shown below.

```
sdir
----train
    ---- class 0 directory
         ----- class 0 image 0
         ----- class 0 image 1
         -----
         ----- class 0 image N
    ---- class 1 directory
         ----- class 1 image 0
         -----
         ----- class 1 image M
    ----
    ---- class 119 directory
         ----- class 119 image 0
         ----- 
         ----- class 119 image K
---- test
    ---- class 0 directory
         ----- class 0 image 0
         ----- class 0 image 1
         -----
         ----- class 0 image N
    ---- class 1 directory
         ----- class 1 image 0
         -----
         ----- class 1 image M
    ----
    ---- class 119 directory
         ----- class 119 image 0
         ----- 
         ----- class 119 image K
```

```
def preprocess (sdir, trsplit):    
    for category in ['training_set', 'test_set']:
        filepaths=[]
        labels=[]
        catpath=os.path.join(sdir, category)
        classlist=os.listdir(catpath)
        for klass in classlist:
            classpath=os.path.join(catpath,klass)
            flist=os.listdir(classpath)
            for f in flist:
                fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
                filepaths.append(fpath)
                labels.append(klass)
        Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
        Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
        if category == 'training_set':
            df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
        else:
            test_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)       
    # split df into train_df and test_df 
    strat=df['labels']    
    train_df, valid_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=123, stratify=strat)    
    print('train_df length: ', len(train_df), '  test_df length: ',len(test_df), '  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))
    print(train_df['labels'].value_counts())
    return train_df, test_df, valid_df

sdir=r'c:\sdir' # set this to the path for your directory
train_split=.9 # set this to the % of the data to use for training
train_df, test_df, valid_df= preprocess(sdir, train_split)
```

Now you have 3 dataframes, a train_df, a valid_df and a test df. Now create the
generators

```
img_size = (224,224) # set this to your desired image size
channels=3 # for color images
image_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], channels)
batch_size= 32 # set this to your desired batch size
length=len(test_df)
# two lines of code below determines batch size for test_gen such that
# test_batch_size X test_steps = number of samples in the test_df.
# this ensures you  go through the test data exactly once.
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
print ( 'test batch size: ' ,test_batch_size, '  test steps: ', test_steps)

trgen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30,
                            width_shift_range=20,
                            height_shift_range=20,
                            horizontal_flip=True,
                            rescale=1/255,
                            zoom_range=0.3,
                            fill_mode='nearest')
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe( ndf, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=test_batch_size)

valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, 
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
```

when you run this if it detects bad image files it should print out a warning and the generator will not use the bad image file. After this create your model and run model.fit to see if the problem is avoided. If not let me know because there are a few other things we can do to detect the errors.